# Use regex to change all matching values in a multiindex column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to follow this:
https://medium.com/swlh/reshaping-in-pandas-with-stack-and-unstack-functions-bb169f64467d

The author shows how to change the column values containing 'Inc' but when I run the code
I get:

`SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`

Code is below.  (1) is the authors code which generates the SettingWithCopyWarning.

I tried (2), which runs without error, but the df loses all other columns and I end up with this:

```
Student A  Labs    100
           Prj     100
Student B  Labs    100
           Prj      80
```

Code:

```
arrays = [['Week 1', 'Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 4'],
          ['1. Python', '2. Github', '3. Matplotlib', '4. SQL', '5. Pokemon', '6. OPP', '7. Pandas', '8. Stats']]

ar2 = [['Student A', 'Student A', 'Student B', 'Student B'],
       ['Labs', 'Prj', 'Labs', 'Prj']]

data = [['Incomplete', 70, 80, 80, 60, 90, 70, 80],
        [100, 70, 70, 70, 60, 80, 70, 80],
        ['Inc01a', 90, 60, 70, 80, 70, 70, 80],
        [80, 90, 70, 80, 90, 80, 100, 90]]
data = np.array(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ar2, columns=arrays)
print(df, '\n')

# Clean up 'Incomplete' type entries.
# (1) df['Week 1']['1. Python'].replace(to_replace=r'^([Ii]nc).*', value=100, regex=True, inplace=True)
# (2) df = df['Week 1']['1. Python'].replace(to_replace=r'^([Ii]nc).*', value=100, regex=True)
print(df, '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh ... figured it out.  Had to use loc():

```
df.loc[:, ('Week 1', '1. Python')].replace(to_replace=r'^([Ii]nc).*', value=100, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Found it here:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy